# How to get an list of element based on given N value

Tags: python

If N=4 than A=[  ]
A array should only get element in size of 4 and after getting N elements need to terminate and append into A[ ]

```
N=4
arr=range(N) 
arr = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print(arr)
```

it allow more than 4 element as we enter...

N=4 ,than i need to get only  4 elements from user,after entering 4th element need to terminate and stop appeding ....

Comment: Loop over `N` times taking input from user. The way you coded does not force any control over the number of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code.

You just need to iterate the loop 4 times & take the input from user.
The input function return the string. so you need to use the int function to type-cast the value in to integer.

**Code :**

```
N=4
arr = [int(input("Enter number : ")) for i in range(1,N+1)]
print(arr)
```

**Output :**

```
Enter number : 5                                                                                                               
Enter number : 6                                                                                                               
Enter number : 3                                                                                                               
Enter number : 2                                                                                                               
[5, 6, 3, 2]
```